# What famous paintings depict Hindu multiverses?

Tags: gods, philosophy, art

If anyone knows any good ones, is there a place I can view these works?

Comment: Don’t have a link but have seen many of these kind of Hindu religious artworks. They show tons of universes within a certain Hindu God or Goddess, I think if you look up Hindu deity photos you’ll find them, they are kind of magnificent to see 

Answer (score 5):

These are some pictures showing multiverse according to vedas abd Puranas. These arts are made according to detail given in puranas.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the Karna Ocean where the multiverse floats in?

Answer (score 1):

Krishna during his life time exhibited "Vishvarupa" several times. Can this depictions qualify for multiverses.